# Rails - Dalli Elasticache not able to connect to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dalli, elastic-cache

Not able to connect to web server when ElastiCache in-transit encryption (TLS) is enabled at elasticsearch

```
cache_endpoint = ENV['M_SERVERS']
cache_options = {
 :compress => true
 }

 elasticache = Dalli::ElastiCache.new(cache_endpoint)
 puts(elasticache.servers)
```

Its throwing error reset peer connect

Tried passing :ssl => true to cache options

If ElastiCache in-transit is false then connection is established

How to connect with ssl.

Rails version 7.0.4
Dalli version 3.2
Dalli ElasticCache version 1.0.1